# How can I display a modal form in response to a click on a MenuItem?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms (Form1 and Form2). I have a MenuItem Help>More Info in Form1. I need a code which does like this...

When  MenuItem Help>More Info in Form1 is clicked Form2 should show but MenuItem More Info should not be disabled. Form1 should get disabled.

In Form2 I have a Button. If I click that button then Form2 should close and Form1 should be enabled.

I can't create object instance of Form2 in Form1's MenuItemMoreInfo_Click because if I click it 10 times then 10 Form2's will open. So, to avoid this I need to disable Form1 after MoreInfo is clicked once.

Comment: I made the title less meaningless and added appropriate tag to question

Answer (score 3):

For this behavior you need to show form2 as a `Dialog`. You will also need to set the `DialogResult` using either a button or via code to ensure it gets closed correctly.

Simply call:

```
new Form2().ShowDialog();
```

in your menu click handler which will show it over the top and disable other forms until `Form2` closes.

If you need to check which button the user clicks, you can use the following:

```
if (new Form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  //the user clicked the button assigned to OK!
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have another question. I want my Form2 to be displayed without title bar and window borders. How to do that? Actually Form2 is an About Box. I want it to be like a splash screen.

Comment: Simply set the forms borderstyle property to none

Answer (score 0):

**Form1 Code:**

```
   private void item1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

**Form 2 Code:**

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).ShowDialog();
    }
```